# rust: how to bind match in a loop

Tags: loops, rust, match

I take input string from user, match it with characters k,f or c. if anything else, returns "input k,f or c".

How do i put "input k,f or c" in a loop so that when the user inputs correct string, i can extract value out of the loop.

my code: (it compiles but not the way i want. can't interact with rust playground terminal but compiles)

```
fn main() {
    println!("K : for Kelvin    C : for Celsius     F : for Fahrenheit : ");
    
    let mut unit = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut unit).expect("Failed to read line");
    
    let unit = unit.trim().to_uppercase();
    println!("unit is {unit} -before match");// this line is for test
    
    let unit:&str = match &*unit{
        "K"=>"K",
        "F"=>"F",
        "C"=>"C",
         _ =>{println!("input k,f or c");return},
    };
    println!("unit is {unit} after match");// this line is for test
    
}
```

I tried putting the block in loop{} and break at error catcher _=> and return unit value.
But i could not catch the value of unit outside of loop{}. Could not compile.

```
fn main() {
    Loop{
    println!("K : for Kelvin    C : for Celsius     F : for Fahrenheit : ");
    let mut unit = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut unit).expect("Failed to read line");
    let unit = unit.trim().to_uppercase();
    println!("unit is {unit} -before match");// this line is for test
    
    let unit:&str = match &*unit{
        "K"=>"K",
        "F"=>"F",
        "C"=>"C",
         _ =>{println!("input k,f or c");break unit},
    };
  }
    println!("unit is {unit} after match");// this line is for test
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the exact opposite of your second attempt, you want to `break` (i.e. exit the loop) once the user put in something valid and `continue` (i.e. repeat the loop) if they don't:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("K : for Kelvin    C : for Celsius     F : for Fahrenheit : ");
    let unit = loop {
        let mut unit = String::new();
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut unit)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        let unit = unit.trim().to_uppercase();
        println!("unit is {unit} before match"); // this line is for test

        break match unit.as_str() {
            "K" => "K",
            "F" => "F",
            "C" => "C",
            _ => {
                println!("please input K,F or C");
                continue;
            }
        };
    };
    println!("unit is {unit} after match"); // this line is for test
}
```

Comment: Bless you. i have spent significant time of my life over it. I wish you good health and a sound mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Great thanks to user cafce25 :)
i have just grouped match pattern and break the loop & taking out the unit value.

```
fn main() {
    let unit = loop {
        println!("K : for Kelvin    C : for Celsius     F : for Fahrenheit : ");

        let mut unit = String::new();
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut unit)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let unit = unit.trim().to_uppercase();
        println!("unit is {unit} -before match"); // this line is for test

        match &*unit {
            "K" | "F" | "C" => break unit,
            _ => {
                println!("input k,f or c");
            }
        };
    };
    println!("unit is {unit} after match"); // this line is for test
}
```